# How to tell a prospective employer that I'm not quite done with college

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, united-states, cover-letter

I've just finished my senior year in college and started looking for web development work. Due to family circumstances, I did poorly on my exams and I'll likely have to retake them next summer. I went to school in another country, so given the usual exam schedule I might be away for a week or so, during which I'd be happy to work remotely.

How interested are employers generally in new hires having an actual diploma, and what's the best way to handle this in cover letters/interviews?

Comment: Does the job listing say "Degree required"?  That will pretty much tell you how important it is to a hiring organization.

Comment: Voted to close as the questions in the last paragraph are impossible to answer. As for the title question, consider the fact that "not quite done with college" and "I won't be graduating for at least another year" are very different things.

Answer (score 4):

First off, don't lie about your degree as that can get you in a whole heap of trouble. Instead, say you will graduate next semester which I'm guessing is the "Fall" semester. On your resume you just simply leave off the "ending" year.

Don't explain why you're graduating next semester. Instead just say that you plan on it. No need to get into details.

Comment: While employers may be OK with not having a degree yet, as long as you tell them, I think you do need to be specific about when you expect to complete.  "Next semester" may be too vague, I would recommend a month and year.

Comment: I definitely wasn't planning to lie, sorry if my post came across that way. I just wasn't sure how to explain looking for a job while my resume shows I'm sitll in college.